# How do I efficiently create a dataframe from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, hash-map

I used this [API](https://declarations.com.ua/api/) to download some data.

The code is supposed to create a dataframe table using specific fields of an object, and it seems to work, but running slow.

I think it would run faster if I used something instead of `json_nomarlize`.

```py
def create_table(data: List[dict]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """ 
    Creates pd.DataFrame using `infocard` values, 
    calculates `income` using `["unified_source"]["step_11"][k]` values.
    Note that `[k]` keys are randomly generated. 
    Please see sample data at the end of the post.
    """

    infocard_container = []
    step_11_container = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        infocard_container.append(json_normalize(data[i]["infocard"]))

        step_11_subcontainer = []
        try:  # if document contains ["unified_source"]["step_11"] field
            for k in data[i]["unified_source"]["step_11"].keys():
                s_df = json_normalize(data[i]["unified_source"]["step_11"][k])[
                    ["person", "sizeIncome"]
                ]
                income_sum = s_df.loc[s_df["person"].eq("1")].sum()["sizeIncome"]
                step_11_subcontainer.append(income_sum)

        except KeyError:  # if not, NaN would be appended
            step_11_subcontainer.append(np.nan) 

        step_11_container.append(step_11_subcontainer)

    df = pd.concat(infocard_container)
    df["income"] = [sum(i) for i in step_11_container]

    assert len(data) == len(df)

    return df
```

---

I need all `data[0]["infocard"]` values, and within `data[0]["unified_source"]["step_11"][k]` values, I need `person`, `sizeIncome` values (and `source_ua_company_code` if possible - it's not in the code). I'm adding all `sizeIncome` values if the `person` == 1

Sample data (data[0]):

```py
{'guid': 'nacp_3bb5b983-edd9...',
 'infocard': {'first_name': 'NAME',
  'patronymic': 'SNAME',
  'last_name': 'SURNAME',
  'office': '"OFFICE"',
  'position': 'POSITION"',
  'source': 'NACP',
  'id': 'nacp_3bb5b983-edd9...',
  'url': 'https://declarations.com.ua/declaration/nacp_3bb5b983-edd9...',
  'document_type': 'Yearly',
  'is_corrected': False,
  'created_date': '2018-03-27T00:00:00',
  'declaration_year': 2017},
 'raw_source': {'url': 'https://public-api.nazk.gov.ua/v1/declaration/nacp_3bb5b983-edd9...'},
 'unified_source': {'step_0': {'declarationType': '1',
   'declarationYear1': '2017'},
  'step_1': {'actual_cityType': '[hidden]',
   'actual_country': '',
   'actual_postCode': '[hidden]',
   'actual_street': '[hidden]',
   'actual_streetType': '[hidden]',
   'changedName': False,
   'city': '[hidden]',
   'cityPath': '[hidden]',
   'cityType': '[hidden]',
   'city_extendedstatus': '1',
   'corruptionAffected': 'No',
   'country': '1',
   'countryPath': '',
   'district': '[hidden]',
   'eng_actualAddress': '[hidden]',
   'eng_actualPostCode': '[hidden]',
   'eng_postCode': '',
   'eng_sameRegLivingAddress': '[hidden]',
   'firstname': 'NAME',
   'housePartNum_extendedstatus': '1',
   'lastname': 'SURNAME',
   'middlename': 'SNAME',
   'postCategory': '',
   'postCategory_extendedstatus': '1',
   'postCode': '[hidden]',
   'postType': '',
   'postType_extendedstatus': '1',
   'previous_firstname': '',
   'previous_lastname': '',
   'previous_middlename': '',
   'region': '[hidden]',
   'responsiblePosition': 'Ні',
   'sameRegLivingAddress': '[hidden]',
   'street': '[hidden]',
   'streetType': '[hidden]',
   'ukr_actualAddress': '[hidden]',
   'workPlace': 'workPlace',
   'workPost': 'workPost',
   'dnt_organization_group': 'n'},
  'step_11': {'1493274700481': {'incomeSource': 'j',
    'iteration': '1493274700481',
    'objectType': 'salary',
    'otherObjectType': '',
    'person': '1',
    'rights': {'1': {'citizen': '',
      'eng_company_address': '',
      'eng_company_code': '',
      'eng_company_name': '',
      'eng_firstname': '',
      'eng_fullname': '',
      'eng_lastname': '',
      'eng_middlename': '',
      'eng_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'eng_postCode': '',
      'eng_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
      'otherOwnership': '',
      'ownershipType': 'property',
      'percent-ownership': '',
      'postCode': '[hidden]',
      'rightBelongs': '1',
      'rights_cityPath': '',
      'ua_apartmentsNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_city': '',
      'ua_company_code': '',
      'ua_company_name': '',
      'ua_firstname': '',
      'ua_houseNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_lastname': '',
      'ua_middlename': '',
      'ua_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_postCode': '',
      'ua_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_street': '[hidden]',
      'ua_streetType': '[hidden]',
      'ua_street_extendedstatus': '',
      'ukr_company_address': '',
      'ukr_company_name': '',
      'ukr_firstname': '',
      'ukr_fullname': '',
      'ukr_lastname': '',
      'ukr_middlename': '',
      'ukr_middlename_extendedstatus': ''}},
    'sizeIncome': 44505.0,
    'source_citizen': '_',
    'source_eng_company_address': '',
    'source_eng_company_code': '',
    'source_eng_company_name': '',
    'source_eng_fullname': '',
    'source_ua_company_code': '000000',
    'source_ua_company_code_extendedstatus': '0',
    'source_ua_company_name': '_',
    'source_ua_firstname': '',
    'source_ua_lastname': '',
    'source_ua_middlename': '',
    'source_ua_sameRegLivingAddress': '',
    'source_ukr_company_address': '',
    'source_ukr_company_name': '',
    'source_ukr_fullname': '',
    'dnt_sizeIncome_hidden': False,
    'dnt_objectType_encoded': 'salarymain',
    'dnt_is_foreign': False},
   '1493274779231': {'incomeSource': '1',
    'iteration': '1493274779231',
    'objectType': 'business',
    'otherObjectType': '',
    'person': '1',
    'rights': {'1': {'citizen': '',
      'eng_company_address': '',
      'eng_company_code': '',
      'eng_company_name': '',
      'eng_firstname': '',
      'eng_fullname': '',
      'eng_lastname': '',
      'eng_middlename': '',
      'eng_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'eng_postCode': '',
      'eng_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
      'otherOwnership': '',
      'ownershipType': 'property',
      'percent-ownership': '',
      'postCode': '[hidden]',
      'rightBelongs': '1',
      'rights_cityPath': '',
      'ua_apartmentsNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_city': '',
      'ua_company_code': '',
      'ua_company_name': '',
      'ua_firstname': '',
      'ua_houseNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_lastname': '',
      'ua_middlename': '',
      'ua_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_postCode': '',
      'ua_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_street': '[hidden]',
      'ua_streetType': '[hidden]',
      'ua_street_extendedstatus': '',
      'ukr_company_address': '',
      'ukr_company_name': '',
      'ukr_firstname': '',
      'ukr_fullname': '',
      'ukr_lastname': '',
      'ukr_middlename': '',
      'ukr_middlename_extendedstatus': ''}},
    'sizeIncome': 19100.0,
    'source_citizen': '',
    'source_eng_company_address': '',
    'source_eng_company_code': '',
    'source_eng_company_name': '',
    'source_eng_fullname': '',
    'source_ua_company_code': '',
    'source_ua_company_name': '',
    'source_ua_firstname': '',
    'source_ua_lastname': '',
    'source_ua_middlename': '',
    'source_ua_sameRegLivingAddress': '',
    'source_ukr_company_address': '',
    'source_ukr_company_name': '',
    'source_ukr_fullname': '',
    'dnt_sizeIncome_hidden': False,
    'dnt_objectType_encoded': 'business',
    'dnt_is_foreign': False},
   '1493275433175': {'incomeSource': 'j',
    'iteration': '1493275433175',
    'objectType': 'pension',
    'otherObjectType': '',
    'person': '1',
    'rights': {'1': {'citizen': '',
      'eng_company_address': '',
      'eng_company_code': '',
      'eng_company_name': '',
      'eng_firstname': '',
      'eng_fullname': '',
      'eng_lastname': '',
      'eng_middlename': '',
      'eng_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'eng_postCode': '',
      'eng_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
      'otherOwnership': '',
      'ownershipType': 'property',
      'percent-ownership': '',
      'postCode': '[hidden]',
      'rightBelongs': '1',
      'rights_cityPath': '',
      'ua_apartmentsNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_city': '',
      'ua_company_code': '',
      'ua_company_name': '',
      'ua_firstname': '',
      'ua_houseNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_lastname': '',
      'ua_middlename': '',
      'ua_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_postCode': '',
      'ua_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_street': '[hidden]',
      'ua_streetType': '[hidden]',
      'ua_street_extendedstatus': '',
      'ukr_company_address': '',
      'ukr_company_name': '',
      'ukr_firstname': '',
      'ukr_fullname': '',
      'ukr_lastname': '',
      'ukr_middlename': '',
      'ukr_middlename_extendedstatus': ''}},
    'sizeIncome': 20075.0,
    'source_citizen': '_',
    'source_eng_company_address': '',
    'source_eng_company_code': '',
    'source_eng_company_name': '',
    'source_eng_fullname': '',
    'source_ua_company_code': '',
    'source_ua_company_code_extendedstatus': '2',
    'source_ua_company_name': '_',
    'source_ua_firstname': '',
    'source_ua_lastname': '',
    'source_ua_middlename': '',
    'source_ua_sameRegLivingAddress': '',
    'source_ukr_company_address': '',
    'source_ukr_company_name': '',
    'source_ukr_fullname': '',
    'dnt_sizeIncome_hidden': False,
    'dnt_objectType_encoded': 'pension',
    'dnt_is_foreign': False}},
  'step_3': {'1493273226784': {'city': '[hidden]',
    'cityPath': '[hidden]',
    'costAssessment': 0,
    'costAssessment_extendedstatus': '2',
    'costDate': 0,
    'costDate_extendedstatus': '2',
    'country': '1',
    'district': '[hidden]',
    'iteration': '1493273226784',
    'objectType': '_',
    'otherObjectType': '',
    'owningDate': 'date',
    'person': '1',
    'postCode': '[hidden]',
    'regNumber_extendedstatus': '1',
    'region': '[hidden]',
    'rights': {'1': {'citizen': '',
      'eng_company_address': '',
      'eng_company_code': '',
      'eng_company_name': '',
      'eng_firstname': '',
      'eng_fullname': '',
      'eng_lastname': '',
      'eng_middlename': '',
      'eng_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'eng_postCode': '',
      'eng_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
      'otherOwnership': '',
      'ownershipType': '_',
      'percent-ownership': '50',
      'postCode': '[hidden]',
      'rightBelongs': '1',
      'rights_cityPath': '',
      'ua_apartmentsNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_city': '',
      'ua_company_code': '',
      'ua_company_name': '',
      'ua_firstname': '',
      'ua_houseNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_lastname': '',
      'ua_middlename': '',
      'ua_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_postCode': '',
      'ua_postCode_extendedstatus': '',
      'ua_street': '[hidden]',
      'ua_streetType': '[hidden]',
      'ua_street_extendedstatus': '',
      'ukr_company_address': '',
      'ukr_company_name': '',
      'ukr_firstname': '',
      'ukr_fullname': '',
      'ukr_lastname': '',
      'ukr_middlename': '',
      'ukr_middlename_extendedstatus': '',
      'dnt_ownershipType_encoded': 'ownproperty'}},
    'totalArea': 32.3,
    'ua_cityType': '_',
    'ua_housePartNum_extendedstatus': '1',
    'ua_postCode': '_',
    'ua_street': '[hidden]',
    'ua_streetType': '[hidden]',
    'dnt_costDate_hidden': True,
    'dnt_costAssessment_hidden': True,
    'dnt_totalArea_hidden': False,
    'dnt_objectType_encoded': 'apt'}}},
 'related_entities': {'people': {'family': []},
  'documents': {'corrected': [], 'originals': []},
  'companies': {'owned': [], 'related': ['_'], 'all': ['_']}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some generators.

Separate out your logic for iterating through your data. For instance, don't form a "subcontainer" list at all since you're just summing it. Also, use `values()` instead of `keys()` for your situation.

```
def step_11(datum: dict)
    for v in datum["unified_source"]["step_11"].values():
        s_df = json_normalize(v)[
            ["person", "sizeIncome"]
        ]
        yield s_df.loc[s_df["person"].eq("1")].sum()["sizeIncome"]

...
df['income'] = [sum(step_11(d)) for d in data]
```

Comment: `data` and `i` will raise a `NameError` unless they are global. Should this be `for v in datum[...].values()`?

Comment: @Reinderien that's just perfect, thanks!